# One column in multicol environment without break

Tags: multicol

Here is a MWE for trying one column content in `multicol` environment without break.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Two columns content
    \item Two columns content
    \item Two columns content
    \item Two columns content
    \item Two columns content
    \item Two columns content
    \item Two columns content
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}

\begin{multicols}{1}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item This item should spanned in one column to look better
    \item This item also should spanned in one column to look better
    \item Again an item to be spanned in one column
    \item Again an item to be spanned in one column
    \item Again an item to be spanned in one column
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

I want this:

[image]

But I got this:

[image]

Comment: If you actually want a gap below 7, use multicol*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume, that text in your document is in one column and that you like to have some lists in two (or more) columns. If I'm right, than in your document example you only need to remove `{multicols}{1}` environment.

**Edit:**
Package `memoir` doesn't support continued numbering in consecutive `enumerate` lists (as far as I know). However it can be simple done by use of the `enumitem` packages as is done in the corrected MWE below:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{enumerate}[series=twocolumn]
    \item Two columns content
    \item Two columns content
    \item Two columns content
    \item Two columns content
    \item Two columns content
    \item Two columns content
    \item Two columns content
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}

\begin{enumerate}[resume*=twocolumn]
    \item This item should spanned in one column to look better
    \item This item also should spanned in one column to look better
    \item Again an item to be spanned in one column
    \item Again an item to be spanned in one column
    \item Again an item to be spanned in one column
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Zarco I need continuity of numbering... 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12...

Comment: @topu, this should not be a problem :-) With `enumitem` is simple, you need to use option `resume`, but for memoir i need to look in package documentation again ... what you can do yourself too ;-)

Comment: @Zarco To look on `memoir` package? I wish if I could find it easily!

Comment: @topu, I checked quickly documentation for the  `memoir` and didn't find find that it support continuation of items numbering. So I suggest to add `enumitem` package  to the your document and than exploit it as is done in edited answer.

Comment: @Zarco, thanks. Actually I had been prepared a solution but was fighting with numbering and the gap inside two lists.

Comment: @topu, sorry, that is not clear from your question :-(.  You not provide the solution how to return to one column list and that the only problem to you is numbering (a XY problem, isn't it?). Anyway, now is solved both of your problems :-)